# Riemann integral of $ f(x)=x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

Can someone suggest a method of finding the Riemann integral of $f(x)=x^2$ on [0,1]. I know that it is sufficient to show $U(P,f)≥1/3≥L(P,f)$ but could not do this. PLease help

Comment: Chose any partition series, for example $$z^{(k)}_i = 2^{-k} i$$
With $0 \leq i \leq 2^k$ and $k \geq 0$. Then compute both values and proceed to finding the limit. Then use continuity of $f$ to generalise to any partiton series $z'^{(k)}$

Comment: You should add your definition of the $U,L$ since some intro calc books use partitions into equal length intervals, while real analysis approach doesn't require equal length.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Partition the interval into $n$ equal parts and take the right endpoints, for instance.

> $$\int_0^1 x^2 dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{n^2}\frac1n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^3} \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^3} \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way of solving it by using a general partition rather than dividing it into n equal parts?

Comment: To find the value of the integral you don't need a general partition. It's proved that continuous functions on bounded closed intervals are Riemann integrable, i.e. the limits for all partitions are equal. Therefore you can use any one partition to calculate the value.

Answer (score 2):

If you break up $[0,1]$ into the intervals $[(n-1)/N, n/N]$ for $n=1,2,\ldots,N$, then for the lower sum you get $(1/N^3)\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} n^2 = (1/N^3) \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} n^2$, and for the upper sum you get $(1/N^3) \sum_{n=1}^N n^2$. If you use the formula for sum of squares given in another answer, you can show that the upper sum and lower sum both converge to $1/3$ as $N \to \infty$.